# Water coming out of drained water heater tank hose

Tags: plumbing, water-heater

I have a leaking tank water heater that I am draining to replace. Cold water input to the tank is shut off. It's now been 18+ hours and I believe the tank has fully drained now. When I turn off the main water valve to the house, nothing further comes out of the drain hose. But when the main water is on (valve to tank still off) water continues to steadily come out of the drain hose attached to the tank. Which tells me that water is somehow still entering the tank even though the tank input valve is closed?

What could be happening here?

Comment: The input/shut off valve is leaking and needs replacing also.

Comment: Ok thanks, that's what I thought, but hoped there weren't two problems at once.

Comment: It could also be from the hot side piping, fed by some cross-connection in the supply system, at a faucet or valve.

Comment: Nothing comes out of hot side faucets, just from the drain hose.

Comment: They usually recommend the quarter turn valves over other types for this reason.

Comment: Quarter turn valve is what I have now

Comment: If your incoming water to your water heater is relatively cold compared to ambient temperature, turn it off your water for a while, and then turn your water back on and put your hand on the incoming cold feed to your water heater and see if it feels cold (from fresh water coming past your valve).  That would help narrow down whether it's coming from the hot or cold into your tank, if you can tell if fresh cold water is flowing past your shutoff valve.

Comment: It doesn't feel like fresh cold water, but it's also coming through a 100' garden hose....so I wonder if that makes it more temperate. Are you saying it could be flowing back from the hot pipes into the tank? Not sure I'm understanding that part.

Comment: To drain a tank, shut off valve and open a faucet to let air in.  A hot water tank you want at least one hot faucet open to break vacuum.  With vacuum it can take a week or more to drain.  Keep faucet/s open when filling tank to remove air.

Comment: Thanks, I did that and I think it's fully drained since nothing comes out when the main water is off. Or am I mistaken here and it may not have fully drained?